# Add basic elements to PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, email, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I use PreferenceActivity to create the settings menu. It is necessary to make [such structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYy62.png) for one of items. Is it possible to create this inside the PreferenceScreen. Within the "Электронная почта" (email) should contain fields with the text of the email and the text "Изменить электронную почтуl" (Change email).

If you click Change email, a window appears where the user types a new address. Then this address should again appear in the line with the text "Электронная почта" (email).

Is it possible to add a TextView to PreferenceScreen?

```
    <PreferenceScreen 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <PreferenceCategory android:title="Настройки">
      <EditTextPreference
      android:defaultValue="@string/default_email"
      android:key="emailPref"
      android:title="Электронная почта" />
```